# I add file names into dataframe but it adds only the same name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, glob

I have a lot of csv files to open and I need to add an extra column with name of those files. For example I have x.csv, y.csv, z.csv and etc. Inside csv file it looks like below:

```
X  Z
1 3
4 5
4 6
```

And it should look like this

```
    X  Z name
    1 3  x
    4 5  x
    4 6  x
    4 5  y
    4 5  y
    1 2  y
```

My code is below but it returns only 1 value...

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import rglob

file_list = rglob.rglob("path", "*")
    
li = []
    
for path in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=None, header=0,)
    file_name = os.listdir('path')[0]
    df["file_name"] = file_name
    li.append(df)
```

Any idea how could I fix it?

Best regards

Comment: I update code. There is no need for "glob". But still the effect is the same

Comment: `file_name = os.listdir('path')[0]` should be `file_name = os.listdir(path)[0]`. If `path` is a fixed string, you'll get the same thing every time indeed

Comment: But it is not it looks: file_name = os.listdir(C:\Users\tomasz.miskiewicz\Desktop\file\)[0]
and inside this file are csv files

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz `os.listdir(...)[0]` returns the first encountered file or directory. It does not return the name of the file. So if each of your directories in `file_list` has identical structure it may result in the described behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `os.listdir` is wrong. `os.listdir` returns a list of files in the directory. You should be using `os.basename` or [`pathlib.Path.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name)

With pathlib:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

file_list = Path("path").rglob("*.csv")
    
li = []
    
for path in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=None, header=0,)
    df["file_name"] = path.name
    li.append(df)
```